# How to compare NSString value with NSMutableDictionary key in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I'm new in development. I don't understand why its not working my code is below

```
if(selectAnswer == [[self.testQuesArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"correct_answer"]
{
    NSLog(@"Correct Answer");
}
```

Where selectAnswer is `NSString`, and correct_answer a 'key' and 0 is the 'value' of this. Please tell me the solution why its not coming in the "If" body ?

Comment: use `isEqualToString:` method instead of **==** ...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string so you have to use isEqualToString in place of "==".

```
if([selectAnswer isEqualToString : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.testQuesArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"correct_answer"]]]
{
NSLog(@"Correct Answer");
}
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
 if ([selectAnswer isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.testQuesArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"correct_answer"]]]) 
   {

   }
```

Comment: Use literals. `[self.testQuesArray[0][@"correct_answer"] stringValue]` would be enough

Comment: And why that `stringWithFormat:@"%@"'? Completely superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Actually right now you are `comparing` two `pointers`(`address of string`) not two `strings`. So Use the ans provided by different friends Like:

```
if([selectAnswer isEqualToString : [self.testQuesArray[0][@"correct_answer"] stringValue])
```

or

```
if([selectAnswer isEqualToString : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.testQuesArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"correct_answer"]]]
```